# How to sum up a column in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i got a dataframe which i convert in an array (that is a testscenario because i have problems with the results in pandas). Now i want to sum up one column.

I have the following code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from tkinter import *


#data_rbu = np.genfromtxt('tmp_fakt_daten.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)
data_rbu = pd.read_excel('tmp_fakt_daten.xlsx')
array_rbu = data_rbu.as_matrix()
print(array_rbu)
summe1 = np.sum(array_rbu, axis=9, dtype=float)
print(summe1)
```

This is the Array! I want to sum up KW_WERT and NETTO_EURO.

After executing the code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\----------\[INPROGRESS] Faktura_sylvia\csv_einlesen bzgl. float\test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    summe1 = np.sum(array_rbu, axis=9, dtype=float)
  File "C:\Users\---------\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 1724, in sum
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Users\----------\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 32, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

I understand that the problem is the axis number.. but i dont know what im exactly doing wrong. I checked the documentation for numpy.sum...

Hope you can help me!

Damian

Comment: Although I commented my thoughts under @JulienBernu's answer, I would suggest you simply do this: `np_arr = data_rbu[['KW_WERT', 'NETTO_EURO']].values # gives you numpy array with just the columns you want`, then `numpy.sum(np_arr, axis=0`, and you will get the same answer. Here is numpy docs on `numpy.sum`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html Check the examples; 4th and 5th examples specifically.

Comment: The reason you are getting the ValueError is that you do not have a 9th axis. Your matrix is 2D. It has only rows and columns. So it has 2 axes: 0 and 1. If it were a 3D matrix (row, col and depth), then it would have 3 axes: 0, 1, 2... and so on. You get the idea. You are trying to sum the 9th column, which is different from the 9th axis. What you need is `numpy.sum(array_rbu[:,7])` for `'KW_WERT'` and `numpy.sum(array_rbu[:,8])` for `'NETTO_EURO'`... Get it? Also, numpy is 0 indexed, so 9th column is the last column (TA), which is a string and cannot be summed... Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the values are in array:

```
In[10]:arr
Out[10]: 
array([['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.15, 18.9, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.145, 18.27, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.145, 18.27, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.15, 18.9, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.15, 18.9, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.145, 18.27, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'B',
        1001380363.0, 'B60ETS', 0.15, 18.9, 'SDH'],
       ['ZPAF', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-31', 'T-HOME ICP', 'E',
        1001380594.0, 'B60ETS', 3.011, 252.92, 'DSLAM/MSAN']], dtype=object)
```

you can do using `arr.sum`:

```
sum_arr=arr.sum(axis=0)
```

`axis=0` it will sum column wise,then you can access the column based on its index.In your case for columns `KW_WERT` and `NETTO_EURO` you can get the sum as:

```
In[25]:sum_arr[7]
Out[25]: 4.046

In[26]:sum_rr[8]
In[23]: 383.33
```

Answer (score 1):

do it directly in pandas:

```
data_rbu = pd.read_excel('tmp_fakt_daten.xlsx')
summe1 = data_rbu['KW_WERT'] + data_rbu['NETTO_EURO'] # gets you a series
summe1.sum() # gets you the total sum (if that's what you are after)
```

Comment: thats the point! I did it already in pandas but i want to check the results in numpy as well

Comment: pandas and numpy are basically the same for numerical values: `summe1.values` will give you the underlying `np.array`. (just the way NaN's or None's are handled may be different, if you have any...) You can do all the same operations using `.values` everywhere. It is just ugly...

Comment: Pandas uses numpy for most, if not all, mathematical computations. Internally (and a simplified picture), numeric pandas columns are numpy arrays, and numpy methods are used on them. So comparing the output from `pandas.DataFrame.sum` to `numpy.sum` is kind of like comparing the same apple to itself, or staring at two copies of the same photograph and trying to identify differences, or looking at yourself in the mirror and checking to see all warts, moles, freckles and dimples are in the same place... Kind of moot, if you ask me.

Comment: @Kartik Not quite. As I mentioned, the way they handle `nan`'s is different: try `pd.DataFrame([0, None]).sum()` and `pd.DataFrame([0, None]).values.sum()`. The first ignores the `nan` and gives `0`, the second gives `nan`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. It is because Pandas automatically drops NaN values. That is how it was created. Numpy, on the other hand, expects users to explicitly use either `numpy.isfinite`, or `numpy.isnan` to filter out NaN. Basically, `pd.DataFrame([0, None]).sum()` is exactly equal to `np.sum(pd.DataFrame([0, None]).dropna(), axis=0)` (since 0 is default axis in `pd.DataFrame.sum`). Apart from this difference in dropping NaN (and a few other quirks here and there), the workhorse is the same beneath both packages.